# Refactor from "val with an arrow in the type" to "def with arguments"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, refactoring

On IntelliJ IDEA for Scala, do we have a refactoring to go from:

`val fun: A => B = {a => ???}`

to:

`def fun(a: A): B = ???`

and back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently do not have this refactoring.